# xamarin.forms scrollView with image is slow in android

Tags: xamarin.forms, scrollview

I have dynamic list with 20~ cells.

I have 3 types of cells so i can't use Listview.

I am using ScrollView that contains StackLayout with the cell elements.

each cell element is also a StackLayout that contains some labels and buttons

the scrolling is smooth.

I have option in each cell to add image by a pressing a button inside the cell.

After the image is added, the scroll is getting very slow when arriving to the cell with the image.

when scrolling beyond the image, the scroll become smooth again

I have also tried TableView but the scrolling is not smooth when presenting the Cells (without adding the image)

How can i improve the rendering of the image ?

Comment: How big is the image in terms of original resolution? For best performance, ensure that the image is an appropriate resolution for the space is occupies on screen - I've found Android in particular takes a huge performance hit when relying on the OS to resize an image to fit the view

Comment: Do you use default Image class to represent images?

Comment: I tried to use both FFIMageLoading and ImageView, same poor result

Answer (score 0):

> I have 3 types of cells so i can't use Listview.

Actually you can use a ListView, by using a [DataTemplateSelector](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/).  As long as you have a collection containing all of the objects to be displayed, and each object in the collection indicates the cell type (usually because of it model's type), ListView with DataTemplateSelector will work great.

Whether you stick with ScrollView or move to ListView, look into [FFImageLoading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading) for displaying images if possible. While it doesn't solve all image display problems, it often does help with responsiveness and image size issues.

Comment: I also tried  DataTemplateSelector, with recycleElement ploicy and also FFImageLoading, and still the rendering is very slow. but if i am presenting the image the first time, i don't understand why the scrolling is slow since the CellView was created allredy